# ActiveAdmin download as only csv format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activeadmin

I would like for ActiveAdmin gem only allow to download collection as csv file . Default it is set to download as xml, csv and json. I would like only allow to download as csv.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an array with the formats that you want to allow downloading. For instance, for only enabling csv you can do the following:

```rb
index download_links: [:csv] do
  column :author
  column :title
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found the link on the bottom of that post. I don't see a date on it, so it might not work anymore, or there might be a better way than monkey patching ActiveAdmin...

https://coderwall.com/p/qzlssg?i=1&p=1&q=author%3Adaviec85&t%5B%5D=daviec85